# Open resty lua script in localhost:8082 not resolving http://localhost/foo/hostname

Tags: nginx, lua, wsl-2, proxypass, openresty

I am trying to access a localhost service (http://localhost/foo/hostname) using an open resty lua script using `proxy_pass` in the wsl-Ubuntu running in a windows 10 machine.

This is the content of **nginx.conf**

```
worker_processes 2;

events {
        worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
        server {
                listen 8082;

                location /{
                        resolver 8.8.4.4;

                        set $target 'localhost/foo/hostname';

                        proxy_pass http://$target;
                }
        }
}
```

I got a '**502 Bad gateway**' response when doing a curl to localhost:8082
This is the error found in the **error.log** file

```
2023/01/27 09:31:17 [error] 331#331: *1 localhost could not be resolved (110: Operation timed out), client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8082"
```

I tried out various solution including modifying the **resolver** option.

Answer (score 0):

This is issue was solved by specifying the **localhost IP address (127.0.0.1)** instead of **localhost** in the specific url.

```
worker_processes 2;

events {
        worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
        server {
                listen 8082;

                location /{
                        resolver 8.8.4.4;

                        set $target '127.0.0.1/foo/hostname';

                        proxy_pass http://$target;
                }
        }
}
```

If anyone know what the actual scenario or reason behind being unable to resolve '**localhost**' but possible with '**127.0.0.1**', kindly share your knowledge.

Comment: 8.8.4.4 doesn't actually resolve `localhost` (can be checked by `nslookup localhost 8.8.4.4 ` for example) - although that'd spit out different error. The error looks more like the resolver isn't accessible by nginx. Maybe try removing the resolver line altogether?